# JavaScript statements won't work after five statements

Tags: javascript, css

```css
#chkinDIV {

        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #roomDIV {

        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #roomcatDIV{


        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }


    #chkoutDIV {

        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #HsetupDIV{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

     #currencyDIV{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;

    }

    #marketDIV{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #travelagDIV{
             width: 100%;
             display: none;
             border-radius: 5px;
             border: 1px solid black;

         }
    #roommasterDIV{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;

    }

    #guestmasterDIV{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #guestmessageDIV{
         width: 100%;
         display: none;
         border-radius: 5px;
         border: 1px solid black;
     }

    #guestlocationDIV{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #forecastDIV{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

     #entryDIV{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #taNewDIV{
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<!--currency-->
    <div id="currencyDIV" >
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Currency</h4>
            <form class="form-inline" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="RoomID">Currency Code:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ccode" onkeypress="validate()">
                    <label for="Room Name">Curreny Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cname" onkeypress="validate()"><br/>
                    <label for="Price">Rate:</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crate" onkeypress="validate()">
                    <label for="Price">Convertion Rate:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ccnverrate" disabled>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <button type="button" id="sub" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="currValidate()">Submit </button>
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick=" document.getElementById('cancel').style.display='none';">Edit </button>
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.getElementById('currencyDIV').style.display='none';">Cancel </button>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>

 <!--rooms DIV-->
    <div id="roomDIV">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Room Type</h4>
            <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="RoomID">Room ID:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rmid">
                    <label for="Room Name">Room Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rmname">
                    <label for="Price">Price:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rmprice"><br/><br/>
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit </button>
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Edit </button><br/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--Check-in DIV-->
    <div id="chkinDIV">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Check - in</h3>
            <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="chkin">Check in ID:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hname">
                    <label for="rsrvid">Reserve ID:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rsrvid">
                    <label for="Arrival">Arrival:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="arrival">
                    <label for="time">Time:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="birthday" value="10/24/2001"/><br/><br/>
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit </button>
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Edit </button><br/>


        </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!--chkout DIV-->

    <div id="chkoutDIV">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Check out</h4>
            <table class="table" >
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Reserve ID</td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chkout_id"></td>
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="birthday" value="10/24/2001"/></td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Hotel setup DIV-->

    <div id="HsetupDIV">
        <div class="container">
            <h4 text align="center">Hotel Setup</h4>
            <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Hotel Name">Hotel Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hname">
                    <label for="Slogan">Slogan:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="slogan">
                    <label for="Phone">E-mail:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                    <label for="Phone">Phone:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneN"><br/><br/>
                    <label for="Slogan">Address Line 1:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adln1"><br/><br/>
                    <label for="Phone">Address Line 2:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adln2"><br/><br/>
                    <label for="Phone">Address Line 3:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adln3"><br/><br/>
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit </button>
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Edit </button><br/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have function to show a specific div [here **currencyDiV**]. This function accept all the divs to variables and check whether the specified div [here **currencyDiV**] is displayed. if not this hides all other divs and display the relevant div [here **currencyDiV**].Though this is intended to do that while executing this executes till [a.style.display="none";] statement and not the below ones. New div is displayed [here **currencyDiV**] below the existing ones without hiding other divs.

This function executes when i pressed a button to display the specified div
[here **currencyDiV**].
This works same for all other functions I wrote to display and hide divs. Up to only four statements those functions are executing

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here or suggest a solution?

```
function currencyDIVshow() {
    var x = document.getElementById("chkinDIV");
    var y= document.getElementById("roomDIV");
    var z=document.getElementById("chkoutDIV");
    var a = document.getElementById("HsetupDIV");
    var b=document.getElementById("roommasterDIV");
    var c = document.getElementById("currencyDIV");
    if (c.style.display === "none") {
        c.style.display = "block";
        y.style.display="none";
        z.style.display="none";
        a.style.display="none";
        b.style.display="none";
        x.style.display="none";
    } else {
        c.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This is the HTML code

```
    <div class="btn-group">
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 50px; background-color:#178bb5; color: black;">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn" href="#" onclick="currencyDIVshow()" role="button" style="margin-bottom: 5px; color: white; text-align: left">Currency</a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

When clicked **currency** div of the **container div** that function is working [here **currencyDIVshow()**] function.

styling

```
 #currencyDIV{
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
```

Comment: Your javascript looks fine, can you also share your HTML code?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code in question? You mentioned that this is will only work while `a.style.display!="none"`, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: I'd imagine that you don't actually have an element with the ID `HsetupDIV`, and so a is null, and you are getting a "cannot read property style of null" error

Comment: dave i am not getting any error

Comment: catcon HTML code is attached to the post

Comment: @S.Hettz: I mean the HTML part which contains all the `div`s you select inside `currencyDIVshow()` method.

Comment: you don't have other divs whose style you are trying to change. Statements are getting null and can't change style of null

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Mat.Now No not yet

Comment: @catcon I am afraid this is a project i am developing and problem i got in the middle. Give me a time i will provide a model

Comment: @catcon HTML of the divs are attahed with style sheets

Answer (score 0):

This approach is a little tricky in my opinion for now now you can use to solutions:

1. Change your statement condition:

   ```
   if(c.style.display !== "block")
   ```
2. Remove `display: none` from css and add display none in javascript before your function:

   ```
   c.style.display = 'none'
   function currencyDIVshow() {
     var x = document.getElementById("chkinDIV");
     var y= document.getElementById("roomDIV");
     var z=document.getElementById("chkoutDIV");
     var a = document.getElementById("HsetupDIV");
     var b=document.getElementById("roommasterDIV");
     var c = document.getElementById("currencyDIV");
     if (c.style.display === "none") {
       c.style.display = "block";
       y.style.display="none";
       z.style.display="none";
       a.style.display="none";
       b.style.display="none";
       x.style.display="none";
     } else {
      c.style.display = "none";
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: @S.Hettz is this enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with id "roommasterDIV"

Therefore your javascript is getting to the line:

```
b.style.display="none";
```

and failing - I would hazard a guess if you comment out that line, or add in an element with that ID, it will work.

Comment: No in my code i have all those divs created without any error